# Pass an Id securely from a web app to an external site

Tags: asp.net, security

We have a SaaS web app and are looking to get some feedback from our users. I was asked to put a button in that would redirect to a feedback page on a site that is external to the one with the service.

I was going to simply include the Id of the client in a query string but I know this is not the best option. I don't really want the user to be able to change the value of this string and thus provide poor data.

I cannot include the feedback page as a part of the web app in question. We would like to store the records in a seperate database where we already keep a lot of reporting information.

It's not really a big deal, I know the query string approach will be easy, but just looking for some alternatives.

I should add that both sites are written in .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Securely-Passing-Identity-Tokens-Between-Websites.aspx

Read this article, it outlines a way that you can use to securely pass tokens from one web application to another. It uses a hashing function and a secret key to guarantee authenticity.

The idea is is that both websites share a secret key. Let's call that $key. Website A creates a hashed representation of the user ID using $key to salt it. For example:

```
$signature = md5($key + $id);
```

Website A then creates a querystring that it appends to the URL of website B. That querystring may look like:

```
?id=$id&signature=$signature
```

Upon reaching Website B, Website B will validate the authenticity of the id by re-hashing the id passed in with the $key outlined above. If it is equal to $signature, then the request is valid. Otherwise the request is ignored.